# How to path to an image file in an electron app?

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-builder

I am creating an electron app and packaging for distribution with electron-builder for windows and Mac. This app creates a folder and some pdfs inside varying based on user input. The pdfs also use an image, which as a node app I was keeping in the root folder of the app.

I managed to write to the desktop using an absolute path.

```
 if (!fs.existsSync(`/Users/${user}/Desktop/2019 Certificates`)){
        fs.mkdirSync(`/Users/${user}/Desktop/2019 Certificates`);
    }
```

but when I use this relative path

```
stampandseal.png
```

I get the following error:

I expect it to find the png relative to the js file, however I get the following error:

```
fs.js:121 Uncaught Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'stampandseal.png'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, you are trying to copy an image from within the app bundle to the user's desktop. Use `__dirname` to reference the directory your code is executing in, and then build the path off of that.

The code below is used by my `main.js` file, which is in the directory containing my `app` directory. I use [upath](https://www.npmjs.com/package/upath) to build the path and [jetpack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fs-jetpack) instead of `fs` for copying

```
var fromPath = upath.join(__dirname, "app", "assets", "image.png");
jetpack.copy(fromPath, toPath, { overwrite: true });
```